# An efficient technique to test if an exponential of logs gives an integer

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Is there an efficient way of testing if the resulting value of an exponential gives an integer without actually expanding the equation.

For example:

$
{\log(12) - \log(4)}=1.09861\ldots
$

and is a transcendental number.

But if we take the exponential, we get an integer:

$
e^{\log(12) - \log(4)}=e^{1.09861\ldots}=3
$

This can be easily shown by proving that the equation is equivalent to $12/3$.

However is there a way to prove this while staying in the logarithm nation... We are assuming that the two numbers $12$ and $4$ are very large...

Can I find say numerical stability bounds to this simple equation:

$
2.71828^{2.48491-1.38629}=3\ldots
$

such that if I use $n$ digits, I will get an integer close the the $n$-th digit.

This may look trivial, but let's assume we do not have say $\log(12)$, but only $2.48491 \ldots$ up to some precision of k-digits. Same thing for $\log(4)$, etc.

Comment: Well, $\log(12)-\log(4) = \log(12/4) = \log(3)$ ...

Comment: $e^{\ln(n)}$ is an integer for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (and it is equal to $n$, obviously)

Comment: Lol.. I understand that the problem looks trivial... Let's assume we do not have say $log(12)$, but only $2.48491\ldots$ up to some precision of $k$-digits... same thing for $log(4)$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your log numbers as $x$ and $y$. Then you can find the upper and lower bound (depending on sign) with $\exp(x\pm\epsilon_x-y\mp\epsilon_y)$ where $\epsilon$ are the errors (something like $0.5/10^{k+1}$). If an integer is not included in the range then you can be certain that it is not an integer.